# Azure Event hub to ADX logs ingestion

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, adx

I am trying to ingest data from event hub to adx. Msgs are coming in event hub but on adx side I see ingesion failures.
Error says - Details": BadRequest_NoRecordsOrWrongFormat: The input stream produced 0 bytes. This usually means that the input JSON stream was ill formed.,

Below is my ingesion properties- "IngestionProperties": [Format=Json/mandatory, IngestionMapping=[{"column":"source","datatype":"","Path":"$.source"},{"column":"ci","datatype":"","Path":"$.ci"},{"column":"ip_address","datatype":"","Path":"$.ip_address"},{"column":"override_change","datatype":"","Path":"$.override_change"},{"column":"priority","datatype":"","Path":"$.priority"},{"column":"scom_severity","datatype":"","Path":"$.scom_severity"},{"column":"assignment_group","datatype":"","Path":"$.assignment_group"},{"column":"assigned_to","datatype":"","Path":"$.assigned_to"},{"column":"short_description","datatype":"","Path":"$.short_description"},{"column":"description","datatype":"","Path":"$.description"},{"column":"identifier","datatype":"","Path":"$.identifier"},{"column":"override_monitor_flag","datatype":"","Path":"$.override_monitor_flag"},{"column":"object_id","datatype":"","Path":"$.object_id"},{"column":"action","datatype":"","Path":"$.action"},{"column":"monitor_details","datatype":"","Path":"$.monitor_details"},{"column":"url","datatype":"","Path":"$.url"},{"column":"alert_id","datatype":"","Path":"$.alert_id"},{"column":"event_time","datatype":"","Path":"$.event_time"}], ValidationPolicy=[Options=ValidateCsvInputConstantColumns, Implications=BestEffort, IsDetailedErrorReportingEnabled=False], Tags=[ToStringEmpty], IngestIfNotExists=[ToStringEmpty], ZipPattern=[null]],

and table structure-

```
.create table EventHubRaw (source : string, ci:string, ip_address: string, override_change:string,priority :string,scom_severity :string,assignment_group :string,assigned_to :string,short_description :string,description :string,
identifier :string,override_monitor_flag :string,object_id :string,action :string,monitor_details :string,url :string,alert_id :string,event_time :string)
```

My ingestion connection of type json. with sample data like below- I tried with TXT, MULTIJSON, CSV formats and none has worked. Any help would be appreciated.

```
source = "SCOM 2019 - LoadTest:$Set1Random";
    ci = "AWSGOBUG123-DBINS";
    ip_address = "11.200.98.$_";
    override_change = "no";
    priority = "Normal";
    scom_severity = "critical";
    assignment_group = " ";
    assigned_to = " ";
    short_description = "The IIS 10 Application Pool named .NET v4.5 on  is unavailable as the Application Pool has been stopped";
    description = "Some Description: $LoadRun";
    identifier = "ID:$Set1Random";
    override_monitor_flag = "false";
    object_id = " ";
    action = "create";
    monitor_details = "AA";
    url = " ";
    alert_id = "AlertId:StaticAlertId";
    event_time = "(Get-Date).ToShortDateString()"
```